# Webpack not running

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I'm trying to run webpack -w but its not running continuously as expected. Earlier it used to rebuild on every save in my code. But now it has stopped working because of which i have to run every time webpack -w in order to make the changes.

Let me know if I need to provide any other information.

```
//package.json
{
  "name": "react",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --color --inline --content-base public/ --history-api-fallback"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "*************"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "homepage": "*********************",
  "dependencies": {
    "flux": "^2.1.1",
    "jquery": "^3.0.0",
    "material-ui": "^0.15.0",
    "react": "^15.1.0",
    "react-bootstrap-table": "^2.3.5",
    "react-dom": "^15.1.0",
    "react-mdl": "^1.5.4",
    "react-router": "^2.4.1",
    "react-tap-event-plugin": "^1.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.9.1",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.4",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.9.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.5.0",
    "http-server": "^0.9.0",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "react-router": "^2.4.1",
    "react-sidenav": "^1.0.4",
    "webpack": "^1.13.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.14.1"
  }
}
```

// webpack.config.js

```
var debug = process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production";
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  context: __dirname,
  devtool: "inline-sourcemap",
  entry: "./app/index.js",
  output: {
    path: __dirname + "/public/",
    filename: "bundle.js"
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      { 
        test: /\.js$/, 
        exclude: /node_modules/, 
        loader: 'babel-loader?presets[]=es2015&presets[]=react' 
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: debug ? [] : [
    new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({ mangle: false, sourcemap: false }),
  ],
};
```

Here it what happens when I run "webpack -w"

```
$ webpack -w
Hash: 5f80fac0cde2c497f037
Version: webpack 1.13.1
Time: 4146ms
             Asset     Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
./public/bundle.js  3.03 MB       0  [emitted]  main
    + 653 hidden modules
$
```

It should keep running my server and look for changes occured.

Comment: It's not very clear what you're asking. My best guess is that you want your local page to refresh in real time when you make an edit in your code. Is that right?

Comment: Yes. Atleast, I don't want to run webpack every time I make any changes.

Comment: Have you tried [React Hot Loader](https://gaearon.github.io/react-hot-loader/getstarted/)?

Comment: @Ursus Thanks for the suggestion. However my question was more like "Why webpack is not running continuously?"

Comment: In my case i have to put watch:true in config

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, Your problem is with webpack hot reloading

For that you need to specify webpack where to look for while hot reloading.
If I'm not wrong, I don't see any mention of in memory location inside your entry object in your config file.

Also, If possible please post the relevant part of your server.js. It would be helpful for us to answer your problem.

Try adding this:

```
entry: [
  'webpack-dev-server/client?http://0.0.0.0:3000', // WebpackDevServer host and port
  'webpack/hot/only-dev-server', // "only" prevents reload on syntax errors
  './app/index.js' // Your appʼs entry point
]
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that I didn't had much available watchers in my system. If this value is too low, the file watcher in Webpack won’t recognize the changes.

```
cat /proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_user_watches
```

Ubuntu users (and possibly others):

```
echo fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288 | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf && sudo sysctl -p.
```

This solves my problem.

Here is the link: [not-enough-watchers](https://webpack.github.io/docs/troubleshooting.html#not-enough-watchers)